# Jquery Bootstrap Slider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Relevant code snippets are below - What am I doing wrong???

Here's the gem I'm using: https://github.com/stationkeeping/bootstrap-slider-rails

**APPLICATION.CSS**

```
* = require_bootstrap-slider
```

**APPLICATION.JS**

```
//
= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
= require underscore
= require gmaps/google
= require bootstrap-slider
```

**INDEX.HTML.ERB**

```
<script>$("#ex8").slider({
            tooltip: 'always'
        });
        </script>
        <input id="ex8" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14"/>
```

**STYLESHEETS DIRECTORY**

[image]

**JS DIRECTORY**

[image]

**THIS IS WHAT I SEE**

[image]

**CONSOLE - ERRORS**

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes this:   localhost:127TypeError: $("#ex8").slider is not a function. (In '$("#ex8").slider({
         tooltip: 'always'
        })', '$("#ex8").slider' is undefined)

Comment: require JS configuration may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating application.js  and css to

#### Application.js

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require bootstrap-slider
```

#### Application.css

```
*= require_bootstrap-slider
```

My personal preference is to use a [CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com)

#### app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js' %>
```

Comment: did not work . still see the same thing i pasted in the question above

Comment: Look at the second solution I posted below.

Comment: didn't work either. i'm editing / adding errors from console to my original question

Comment: @hikmatyar Make sure you include the links below after you include application.js and application.css in the layout. And your `= require` statements should be preceded with `//` like `//= require jquery`

Comment: What is the console saying now?

Comment: same as what i posted in the original question, minus the '...requires Jquery' error